# Grabbing values from masked image areas OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

So this is a fun one. I have a template image that i want to grab grayscale values from. I do this by masking out some circles around the center of the image and attempt to find the *average* values within those masked out circles. However, the values that im getting arent  making any sense.

[image]
[image]

[image]

When i use this image I get the set of lists below. All of these should contain nearly identical values(or the values should be shifted down the list but remain in the same order) because they are exactly the same picture. I don't know whats going on but i think it begins with ****indices = np.where(dst != 0)[0]****. i cant tell what indices's values actually represent. i want the grayscale values from the x,y positions that arent zeros so that i can average them. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[171, 180, 187, 190, 189, 185, 181, 178]

[169, 178, 184, 186, 184, 179, 174, 172]

[166, 175, 183, 188, 189, 186, 182, 179]

[148, 155, 163, 171, 175, 176, 174, 171]

[153, 162, 171, 177, 180, 179, 175, 172]

[43, 46, 53, 61, 68, 71, 70, 68]

[41, 44, 51, 59, 66, 69, 68, 66]

[42, 45, 52, 60, 67, 70, 69, 67]

[41, 44, 51, 59, 66, 69, 68, 66]

[45, 52, 60, 68, 72, 72, 70, 67]

As you can see the lines are generally the same -which they should be- but the values are greatly different.

[image]

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

radius = 15
cp = 5

image = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\All\\images\\stamptemplate.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
yepo = gray.copy()
gray = 255 - gray
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for cnts in contours:   
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnts)
    x,y = rect[0]
    w,h = rect[1]
    w = int(w)
    h = int(h)
    angle = int(rect[2])
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    area = w*h
    if area > 1000:
        #print (int(float(area)), int(rect[2]))
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        #cv2.drawContours(overlay,[box],0,(0,255,0),cv2.FILLED)
        mask = np.zeros(gray.shape, np.uint8)
        ang = angle
        data = []
        for i in range(8):
            x2 =  int(round(x + (radius+10) * math.cos(ang * math.pi / 180.0)))
            y2 =  int(round(y + (radius+10) * math.sin(ang * math.pi / 180.0)))
            cv2.circle(mask, (x2,y2), cp, (255, 255, 255), -1)
            ang += 45



            dst = cv2.bitwise_and(yepo, mask)
            indices = np.where(dst != 0)[0]
            average = np.mean(indices)
            data.append(int(average))
        cv2.imshow("blackout",dst)
        cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF== ord('q')
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        print(data)
```

Comment: I think the problem is occurring at np.where part. Use np.argwhere() instead and remember, it returns coordinates in [y, x] format, not in [x, y] format. And in the next line, why are you taking the mean of indices whereas you wish to get the mean of colours at those indices.? Check that also.

Comment: Okay so, i noticed that mess up now thank you. i added more check points and was getting a bunch of sine waves and didn't know why...It because i was tracking either the X or Y position over those points thus, a sine wave...So i guess now the question is how can i grab the grayscale values at those (y,x) pair points?

Comment: @Mogarbobac You can edit the question instead of mentioning on commments